# Can somebody recommend a UPS which would allow me to powercycle devices via IP?

Tags: hardware, ups

I need to purchase a UPS which I can manage remotely and powercycle individual items on via some sort of IP interface.

The unit doesn't need to be that powerful, 750 Va would suffice, but the IP interface is extremely important.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had excellent results with this: http://www.digital-loggers.com/epcr2.html. It's flexible, reliable, and inexpensive. Also, the company is responsive. This isn't a UPS, but you can put it between a UPS and whatever equipment is powered by the UPS.